# How do I fetch data from pdo by columns?

Tags: php, pdo

```
number | alphabet
   1   |    A
   2   |    B
   3   |    C

result: [
  ["number"] => [ 1, 2, 3 ]
  ["alphabet"] => [ "A", "B", "C" ]
]
```

I want to get this result.

```
$data = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  foreach ($data as $row => $columns) {
    foreach ($columns as $row2 => $column2) {
      $retData[$row2][$row] = $column2;
    }
  }

return $retData;
```

I use this loop. But I want to know if I can do this output with just PDO.

Comment: With `PDO` only you can't. You have to apply some sort of loop or some predefined array methods to achieve your goal

Comment: A bit modification in your code:-https://3v4l.org/BULEJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it can't, but you can try this if you want specific columns

```
//array
$number = [];
$alphabet = [];

while ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $number[] = $row["number"];
    $alphabet[] = $row["alphabet"];
}
```